# How to implement a DocuSign template natively into a Webflow site?

Tags: docusignapi, webflow

I have a webflow site with an order form. Once the prospect completes the order form and presses submit, the goal is to redirect the prospect to another page on the webflow site (not redirect to a DocuSign page).

On the next page, the prospect would see our customer agreement with their data from the order form already prefilled. We have a DocuSign template already with tabs already placed visually, we can map those labels to the form labels on the order form. All that should be left for prospects to do is to add their signature and submit the agreement.

If I understood the explanation above correctly, then the following steps would work our use case as well. Is this correct?

Step 1 When a prospect fills in and submits the order form on the website, the website button click will trigger a GET API request. ie. GET demo.docusign.net/restapi/login_information

Step 2 Next, a POST API request will be sent to DocuSign to create an envelope based on our template agreement. i.e. POST demo.docusign.net/restapi/:version/:accountId/envelopes In this POST request, we will also send in the request body the data labels in the template and map those to the data entered in the form submission. i.e.

```
"tabs":  {
    "textTabs":  [
        {
            "tabLabel": "address",
            "value": "Code for pulling the value from the relevant form field"
        },
        {
            "tabLabel": "email",
            "value": "Code for pulling the value from the relevant form field"
        }
    ]
}
```

Step 3 Call the following GET request to display the DocuSign agreement directly on our site. --> Should this be in an iframe or another implementation? i.e. Get DocuSign Recipient View

Thank you in advance for your support!

Comment: what is your question? do you have an issue? are you just asking to validate your understanding ?

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your question! I would like to know if these are the steps I should implement to solve my specific use case, or is there soemthing that I am missing?

Comment: yes, that is correct. You do need to obtain an auth token, not sure if you thought about how to do that. You can have the user log in if that works for you using Auth Code Grant.

Comment: Hi Inbar, thank you for the reply! In this use case, the user does not have an account.

Comment: Is there an alternative to using Auth Code Grant for this use case?

Comment: you can use JWT, why are you not happy with Auth Code Grant?